# How to make a file with Python but more formatted

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a way I can make the data in the file more professional looking preferably a table

Here is an example:

```
Pos       Lang    Percent  
1         Python  33.2         
2         Java     23.54    
3         Ruby     17.22        
4         Groovy    9.22     
5         C         1.55          
6         Lua       10.55
```

And here is my code:

```
data = (name, last_name, age, company, hourly_rate, occupation, savings, deposits)
answer_three = input("Would you like to print your data in a file? yes/no: ")
if answer_three == "yes":
    file = open(r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Description.txt","w+")
    file.write(str(data))
```

But when I print the file on my desktop it looks like this:

```
('
'Name', 'Last Name', 'Age', 'Company', Hourly Rate, 'Occupation', Your Savings, Deposits)
```

My desired result:

```
First Name -- Last Name -- Age -- Company -- Hourly Rate -- Occupation -- Your Savings -- Deposits
*name*     *last*   *age* *company* *hourly* *occupation* *savings* *deposits*
```

I hope this makes sense I just want it to look a little more nicer than it already is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you parsing the data? How does the data enter your program, by manual input or from another file?
Would you be up to use for example pandas to print the data in excel/csv files?

Comment: @AlejandroA You don't need to get and learn Pandas to write CSV files, you know.

Comment: This [website](https://www.educba.com/python-print-table/) shows multiple ways to make your table more human readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [built-in `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) should do nicely for what you'd like.

You can tune the CSV dialect for the formatting you prefer.

```
import csv

header = [
    "First Name",
    "Last Name",
    "Age",
    "Company",
    "Hourly Rate",
    "Occupation",
    "Your Savings",
    "Deposits",
]

with open(r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Description.txt", "w+") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow([str(d) for d in data])
```

If you want a more human-readable view, you could look at e.g. [the `tabulate` package on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/).

Of course, a tabulation library is a decently fun exercise to write yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use prettytable module. Here is an example output:

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide  | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin    | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart    | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth     | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

If you prefer no border, use: `table.border = False`.
Link: https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/